# How do I make a Clippy (Windows virtual assistant) clone?

Tags: windows

What languages and technologies should I use? I need to place an image over all the other windows and change that image sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

Any UI technologies that allows you drawing topmost transparent window.

From Windows API:

See `WS_EX_LAYERED` / `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`  / `UpdateLayeredWindow` to draw transparent window

See `WS_EX_TOPMOST` to draw topmost window.

The UI framework you use might incapsulate these APIs with its own mechanisms.